# Start python Process with output and timeout

Tags: python, timer, process, output

I'm trying to find the way to start a new Process and get its output if it takes less than X seconds. If the process takes more time I would like to ignore the Process result, kill the Process and carry on.

I need to basically add the timer to the code below. Now sure if there's a better way to do it, I'm open to a different and better solution.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    # Ugly work
    q.put(['hello', 'world'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()
    p.join()
```

Thanks!

Comment: see [Timeout on a Python function call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492519/4279) specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following module useful in your case:

**Module**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Allow functions to be wrapped in a timeout API.

Since code can take a long time to run and may need to terminate before
finishing, this module provides a set_timeout decorator to wrap functions."""

__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell ' \
             '<stephen.paul.chappell@atlantis-zero.net>'
__date__ = '18 December 2017'
__version__ = 1, 0, 1
__all__ = [
    'set_timeout',
    'run_with_timeout'
]

import multiprocessing
import sys
import time

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60


def set_timeout(limit=None):
    """Return a wrapper that provides a timeout API for callers."""
    if limit is None:
        limit = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    _Timeout.validate_limit(limit)

    def wrapper(entry_point):
        return _Timeout(entry_point, limit)

    return wrapper


def run_with_timeout(limit, polling_interval, entry_point, *args, **kwargs):
    """Execute a callable object and automatically poll for results."""
    engine = set_timeout(limit)(entry_point)
    engine(*args, **kwargs)
    while engine.ready is False:
        time.sleep(polling_interval)
    return engine.value


def _target(queue, entry_point, *args, **kwargs):
    """Help with multiprocessing calls by being a top-level module function."""
    # noinspection PyPep8,PyBroadException
    try:
        queue.put((True, entry_point(*args, **kwargs)))
    except:
        queue.put((False, sys.exc_info()[1]))


class _Timeout:
    """_Timeout(entry_point, limit) -> _Timeout instance"""

    def __init__(self, entry_point, limit):
        """Initialize the _Timeout instance will all needed attributes."""
        self.__entry_point = entry_point
        self.__limit = limit
        self.__queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.__process = multiprocessing.Process()
        self.__timeout = time.monotonic()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Begin execution of the entry point in a separate process."""
        self.cancel()
        self.__queue = multiprocessing.Queue(1)
        self.__process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=_target,
            args=(self.__queue, self.__entry_point) + args,
            kwargs=kwargs
        )
        self.__process.daemon = True
        self.__process.start()
        self.__timeout = time.monotonic() + self.__limit

    def cancel(self):
        """Terminate execution if possible."""
        if self.__process.is_alive():
            self.__process.terminate()

    @property
    def ready(self):
        """Property letting callers know if a returned value is available."""
        if self.__queue.full():
            return True
        elif not self.__queue.empty():
            return True
        elif self.__timeout < time.monotonic():
            self.cancel()
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def value(self):
        """Property that retrieves a returned value if available."""
        if self.ready is True:
            valid, value = self.__queue.get()
            if valid:
                return value
            raise value
        raise TimeoutError('execution timed out before terminating')

    @property
    def limit(self):
        """Property controlling what the timeout period is in seconds."""
        return self.__limit

    @limit.setter
    def limit(self, value):
        self.validate_limit(value)
        self.__limit = value

    @staticmethod
    def validate_limit(value):
        """Verify that the limit's value is not too low."""
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError('limit must be greater than zero')
```

---

To use, see the following example that demonstrates its usage:

**Example**

```
from time import sleep


def main():
    timeout_after_four_seconds = timeout(4)
    # create copies of a function that have a timeout
    a = timeout_after_four_seconds(do_something)
    b = timeout_after_four_seconds(do_something)
    c = timeout_after_four_seconds(do_something)
    # execute the functions in separate processes
    a('Hello', 1)
    b('World', 5)
    c('Jacob', 3)
    # poll the functions to find out what they returned
    results = [a, b, c]
    polling = set(results)
    while polling:
        for process, name in zip(results, 'abc'):
            if process in polling:
                ready = process.ready
                if ready is True:       # if the function returned
                    print(name, 'returned', process.value)
                    polling.remove(process)
                elif ready is None:     # if the function took too long
                    print(name, 'reached timeout')
                    polling.remove(process)
                else:                   # if the function is running
                    assert ready is False, 'ready must be True, False, or None'
        sleep(0.1)
    print('Done.')


def do_something(data, work):
    sleep(work)
    print(data)
    return work


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Had to change clock() by a datetime since it's running on a raspberry pi and the original code was not working fine.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Does the process you are running involve a loop?
If so you can get the timestamp prior to starting the loop and include an if statement within the loop with an sys.exit(); command terminating the script if the current timestamp differs from the recorded start time stamp by more than x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to adapt [the queue example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to your case is to pass the timeout to the `q.get()`  call and terminate the process on timeout:

```
from Queue import Empty
...

try:
    print q.get(timeout=timeout)
except Empty: # no value, timeout occured
    p.terminate()
    q = None # the queue might be corrupted after the `terminate()` call
p.join()
```

Using a `Pipe` might be more lightweight otherwise the code is the same (you could use `.poll(timeout)`, to find out whether there is a data to receive).